# Text color formatting not working

Tags: html, css, colors

I am trying to change the color if the color of the text portion "Click here for more details". There is no change in color when i have applied the color parameter as blue.

```
{% if value == 'Windows Server' %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;font-weight:400;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/000"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>
{% elsif value == 'SharePoint' %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/111"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>
{% elsif value == 'Remote Site' %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/1"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>
{% elsif value == 'NAS' %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/2"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>
{% elsif value == 'Linux Server' %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/112"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>
{% else %}
<p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color=blue"><p style="color: blue; background-color: white"></b>No Dashboard Found</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: **Don't** use inline css for this use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you wrote `color=blue` instead of `color:blue`. You did all the rest of the inline css correctly, but you must have just gotten mixed up and forgot about the format for the last bit.

Comment: Tried the change, but no luck <p style="font-size: 15px;background-color:#ccffff;color:blue"

Comment: The `a` tag default styling is probably overriding it. Put the color on the `<a>` instead of the `<p>`.

Comment: I am sorry dint get that..Where should i place the color parameter ?           
  <p style="font-size: 15px;font-weight:400;background-color:#ccffff;color:blue"><a href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/1793"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>

Comment: @sudeep, paige means like this : <p style="font-size: 15px;font-weight:400;background-color:#ccffff;color:blue"><a style="color:blue" href="https://d-looker.sys.cigna.com/dashboards/000"><b>Click here for more details.</b></a></p>

Comment: Thank you so much jsanchezs and Paige. It worked...